# Не воспроизводит музыку в дискорде. Постоянно пишет, Что бот не подключен

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Не очень понимаю почему так. У меня был еще один пример кода, но там все совсем не работало. Бот подключался, но писало ошибку Связанную с Extract auido. Ну не суть.

youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''
ytdl_format_options = {
'format': 'bestaudio/best',
'restrictfilenames': True,
'noplaylist': True,
'nocheckcertificate': True,
'ignoreerrors': False,
'logtostderr': False,
'quiet': True,
'no_warnings': True,
'default_search': 'auto',
'source_address': '0.0.0.0' # bind to ipv4 since ipv6 addresses cause issues sometimes
}
ffmpeg_options = {
'options': '-vn'
}

```
ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)
class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
def __init__(self, source, *, data, volume=0.5):
    super().__init__(source, volume)
    self.data = data
    self.title = data.get('title')
    self.url = ""
@classmethod
async def from_url(cls, url, *, loop=None, stream=False):
    loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
    data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream))
    if 'entries' in data:
        # take first item from a playlist
        data = data['entries'][0]
    filename = data['title'] if stream else ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
    return filename
    
@bot.command(name='Сюда', help='Подключает бота к войсу')
async def join(ctx):
    if not ctx.message.author.voice:
        await ctx.send("{} Ты не подключен, лошок".format(ctx.message.author.name))
        return
    else:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
@bot.command(name='Пиздуй', help='Лив бота с войса')
async def leave(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    if voice_client.is_connected():
        await voice_client.disconnect()
    else:
        await ctx.send("Суки, выгоняют меня")
@bot.command(name='Сыграй', help='Играет музыку')
async def play(ctx,url):
    try :
        server = ctx.message.guild
        voice_channel = server.voice_client
        async with ctx.typing():
            filename = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=bot.loop)
            voice_channel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable=filename, source=filename))
        await ctx.send('**Сейчас играет:** {}'.format(filename))
    except:
        await ctx.send("Ошибка где-то здесь!!")
@bot.command(name='Притормози', help='Ну пауза типа')
async def pause(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    if voice_client.is_playing():
        await voice_client.pause()
    else:
        await ctx.send("Сейчас zxcбот ничего не играет")
    
@bot.command(name='Газуй', help='Продолжает воспроизводить')
async def resume(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    if voice_client.is_paused():
        await voice_client.resume()
    else:
        await ctx.send("До этого zxcбот нихуя не играл. Юзни '?:Сыграй' ")
@bot.command(name='Стопай', help='Останавливает музыку')
async def stop(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    if voice_client.is_playing():
        await voice_client.stop()
    else:
        await ctx.send("Сейчас zxcбот ничего не играет")
```

Comment: Используйте lavalink

Comment: Ух ты ж. Впервые слышу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем и целом, решением проблемы стала отдельная установка ffmpeg через powershell и небольшим редактированием настроек.

```
ytdl_format_options = {
'format': 'bestaudio/best',
'outtmpl': 'downloads/%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
'restrictfilenames': True,
'noplaylist': True,
'nocheckcertificate': True,
'ignoreerrors': False,
'logtostderr': False,
'quiet': True,
'no_warnings': True,
'default_search': 'auto',
'source_address': '0.0.0.0' # bind to ipv4 since ipv6 addresses cause issues sometimes
```

}
ffmpeg_options = {
'before_options': '-nostdin',
'options': '-vn'
}

Вот нынешние настройки

Если через powershell не вышло, то тогда просто устанавливаем rar ffmpeg, переносим в папку с кодом(Это не обязательно. Мне так удобнее) и в команде "Сыграй" прописываем следующее:

```
voice_channel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="C:/Python/dicsord_bot/ffmpeg-2022-03-03-git-72684d2c2d-full_build/bin/ffmpeg.exe", source=filename))
```

executable - Путь до назначенной папки с exe файлом ffmpeg'a

(https://github.com/adaptlearning/adapt_authoring/wiki/Installing-FFmpeg) Вот сайт для установки + руководство